# How can I return a value based on the most recent date using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I hope to get some suggestions please. My data is as follow:

| MyDate | MyValue |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 1000 |
| 02/01/2021 | 5000 |
| 03/01/2021 | 6000 |

I want to return the most recent 'MyValue' based on most recent date which is in this example: 6000 since 03/01/2021 is the most recent date.

I was thinking to do the following but found it challenging as I am new to VB.Net

```
Dim myDate as Date
Dim myValue as Decimal

IF Max(myDate) Then
   return myValue
Else
   return 0
End If
```

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<Integer, DateTime>`, then you can just look it up by the integer key.  Or vice-versa, not sure which is a key in your example.

Comment: You need to load this data into some sort of collection first off, then you could use something like a linq query to find the collection item with the max date

Comment: It's impossible to see what date format you are using, US or GB. If you would use sample dates with a day > 12 no guessing would be needed.

Comment: Are you reading this data from a file?

Comment: You are retrieving this data from somewhere. How are you storing it? A DataTable? A List(Of T)? What?

Comment: The data is coming from a CSV file and the date is in US format. The current code I have is complaining about not being able to convert date to boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Store everything into a `Dictionary<Date,Decimal>`, and get max value `myDictionary.Keys.Max()`